# php regex number and + sign only

Tags: php, regex

I need a php function to validate a string so it only can contains number and plus (+) sign at the front.

Example:

**+632444747** will return true
**632444747** will return true
**632444747+** will return false
**&632444747** will return false

How to achieve this using regex?

Thanks.

Comment: try it here https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Something like this

```
preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', $str);
```

Testing it

```
$strs = array('+632444747', '632444747', '632444747+', '&632444747');
foreach ($strs as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', $str)) {
        print "$str is a phone number\n";
    } else {
        print "$str is not a phone number\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
+632444747 is a phone number
632444747 is a phone number
632444747+ is not a phone number
&632444747 is not a phone number
```

Comment: Mikel: it's like providing an answer to something that can be read off the manual. RTFM, I would say.

Comment: OP asked for a function.  Take the meat of this answer and sandwich it into:
function isValidPhoneNo($str) {}
:)

Comment: Note: Does not work if there is a space in the number, e.g. `+49 123456`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

var_dump(preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '+123'));
var_dump(preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '123'));
var_dump(preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '123+'));
var_dump(preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '&123'));
var_dump(preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', ' 123'));
var_dump(preg_match('/^\+?\d+$/', '+ 123'));

?>
```

only the first 2 will be true (1).  the other ones are all false (0).